# Website won't work without www on mobile phone

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mobile

I have updated the *.htaccess* file so that when someone types in `example.com`, they are redirected to `www.example.com`. This works great on my computer, but when I try it on my cell phone is does not redirect. Instead I get the "Webpage not available" message. Does anyone know why? I've designed many websites and have never run into this problem.

Comment: What previously happened before you put in the redirect?

Comment: This seems highly unlikely to be related to the redirect.

Comment: I didn't check before, but I took out the redirect and I still get the same thing on my phone. Any suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried connecting on your cell phone via a Wi-Fi network  instead of your cell network (or vice-versa)? It is possible that your cell operator or ISP is caching the old version of the site before you set up the redirect.

Comment: You seem to have deleted the DNS records for your non-www name as they don't resolve on my machine. I can't access the website without www, and I'm on a desktop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your DNS configuration. There is no DNS record for `byerswrecker.com` so it won't resolve to any IPs, but `www.byerswrecker.com` resolves to your hosting provider IP and works! You should have DNS cached on your PC but not on your phone, so it works on your PC but not on your phone.